# How to deal with slow Dataflow jobs that uses GroupByKey?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pretty large table (in TBs) in Big Query and below is the example of the data i have

```
------------------------------------------------------
|   date       |   id     |   no_items |   unique_id  |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   2018-01-01 |    ifg   |      4     |    AA1       |
|   2018-01-01 |    hui   |      8     |    AA1       |
|   2018-01-01 |    bhi   |      12    |    AA2       |
|   2018-01-02 |    hui   |      3     |    AA1       |
|   2018-01-02 |    ifg   |      10    |    AA1       |
|   2018-01-02 |    bhi   |      5     |    AA2       |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I have created a beam job that reads and writes into Avro. I am doing GroupByKey using id and unique_id and then comparing the no_items for each of the dates. If the difference between no_items between two dates is more than 5. I am creating a new PCollection with new fields and one extra field that takes the previous of no_items.But the dataflow job is taking long time to complete even with 25 workers and worker_machine_type as 'n1-highcpu-64'

Below is the BEAM pipeline I had written

```
def sort_grouped_data(element):
    key, value = element
    value = list(value)
    value.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    return [element]

def final_segment(element):
    key, value = element
    value = list(value)
    length = len(value)
    for i in range (0, length):
     if abs(value[length - i][1] - value[length - (i + 1)][1]) > 5:
            segment = {"segment_id": segment_id, "segment_start_date": value[length - 1][2],
                       "segment_end_date": value[length - (i + 1)][2], "id": key[1], "unique_id": key[0],
                       "new_value": value[length - i][1]}
    return [segment]


input_or_inputs(
            | "get_key_tuple" >> beam.Map(lambda element: ((element["unique_id"], element["id"]),
                                                           [element["date"], element["no_itmes"]]))
            | "group_by_id_unique_id" >> beam.GroupByKey()
            | "sort_grouped_data" >> beam.ParDo(sort_grouped_data)
            | "final_segment" >> beam.ParDo(final_segment)
)
```

I feel the dataflow job is slow because of two reasons

1. Due to the sorting
2. Due to the comparison between each of the elements, and when the data is huge it is getting slower.

Can anyone help me with this? Is it possible to optimize the code to make it more faster?

Comment: Is it batch or streaming pipeline?

Comment: It is batch pipeline

Comment: I would recommend that you review Dataflow Shuffle service to improve the performance of the job. More details can be found here - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shuffle

Comment: +1 on use of shuffle service.  Also does your data have any hot keys with the composite key you are creating for the GBK?

Comment: When you run pipeline, where does it spend most time: in GBK or in further processing (sort_grouped_data/final_segment)? (In final segment you're looping through all the items, while overwriting segment value. Might be worth moving return statement under if)

Comment: Firstly, I would ask you to access the _Job Monitoring charts_ and then _Job Graph_  in the [Dataflow monitoring interface](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf) to check which step is taking you this more time then the others. After you open the graphic visualisation of your pipeline, just check _Wall time_ , which is the time taken the step by dedicated workers.  Which step is taking longer than the others? So we can continue investigating.

Comment: So the most time is taken by step final_segment, and the running time for it goes upto 6 days. I think it is due to the looping through all the items. Could you please let me know is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: @tank, Yes, the issue might lie within the for loop, since you have a significantly big table, the len(value) might be very large. About optimisation, can you filter your data just with the date difference is more than 5 days then create your Pcollection?